# GIT - Splitting folder structure for distributed work

Tags: git

I have a bit of a problem and somehow I cannot find what I want no matter what I tried (mostly with `git filter-branch` variations)

So, let's assume this simplified directory structure

```
/modules/subfolder1
        /subfolder2
        /subfolder3

/somethingElse/one
              /two
```

I want now another branch that will contain just

```
/modules/subfolder1
        /subfolder2
```

This branch will be pushed to another repo where someone will change the contents inside `subfolder2`. That someone else will push it and then I will pull it and merge it in the initial branch.

Here I have the problems, at the merge.

1. I want just to merge `subfolder1` and `subfolder2`. And because `subfolder1` has not been changed by me I expect NO conflicts.
2. The contents of `subfolder3` and `/somethingElse/*` should be left untouched (NOT deleted).

I cannot actually solve both points in the same time. One solution correctly merges, but deletes incorrectly, the other one does not delete what it shouldn't, but it always have conflicts on changes.

It is also worth noting that I cannot remove `/subfolder1` and `/subfolder2` from my initial branch and totally split this repo in 2 repos.

Is it even possible to do this ?

Small update : I will not need to do this merge very often, so I do not need a super performant solution, I can do some manual work or write a script.

Comment: You use the term 'submodule', but is it a 'git submodule'? If so, then each submodule is actually a different repository so there is not such problem at all. If it is not a 'git submodule' please use a different term such as 'sub-folder' or a similar one.

Comment: No, no it it just a random folder name, I have updated the folder names

Comment: OK, so now it is clear, and I suggest that you'll convert all sub-folders into git submodules (meaning that each of it is a separate repository and you'll leave that original repository as a root repository that points to sub-modules). This will give you ability to work on each repository separately, and on a group of repositories as well when needed.

Comment: @yorammi I do not know how fesable is that tough, I have about 50 subfolders and also normal files that are in the root repo (not in folders). Or do you mean I will convert just subfolder1 and subfolder2 from my example in submodules ? That would work...

Comment: You can convert only the 2 sub-folders and keep the others folders and files in the original repository. It should work.